# com.amazonaws.transform.JsonErrorUnmarshaller: method <init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V not found

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, logback, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We are using a library called logback-ext-cloudwatch-appender to send our logback-based logs to AWS Cloudwatch.  This is what the dependency looks like in our pom.xml file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eluder.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-ext-cloudwatch-appender</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

A few days ago these errors started appearing in our logs.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.transform.JsonErrorUnmarshaller: method <init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V not found
    at com.amazonaws.services.logs.model.transform.InvalidParameterExceptionUnmarshaller.<init>(InvalidParameterExceptionUnmarshaller.java:26)
    at com.amazonaws.services.logs.AWSLogsClient.init(AWSLogsClient.java:280)
    at com.amazonaws.services.logs.AWSLogsClient.<init>(AWSLogsClient.java:275)
    at com.amazonaws.services.logs.AWSLogsClient.<init>(AWSLogsClient.java:248)
    at org.eluder.logback.ext.cloudwatch.appender.AbstractCloudWatchAppender.doStart(AbstractCloudWatchAppender.java:100)
    at org.eluder.logback.ext.aws.core.AbstractAwsEncodingStringAppender.start(AbstractAwsEncodingStringAppender.java:123)
    at org.eluder.logback.ext.cloudwatch.appender.AbstractCloudWatchAppender.start(AbstractCloudWatchAppender.java:95)
    at ch.qos.logback.ext.spring.DelegatingLogbackAppender.getDelegate(Unknown Source)
    at ch.qos.logback.ext.spring.DelegatingLogbackAppender.append(Unknown Source)
    at ch.qos.logback.ext.spring.DelegatingLogbackAppender.append(Unknown Source)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:84)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:48)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:270)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:257)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:421)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.info(Logger.java:579)
    (truncated)
```

I found out that we had upgraded to AWS 1.11.5, but I couldn't find any evidence of such a bug in that release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the current version of logback-ext-cloudwatch-appender has a transitive dependency on a specific version of aws-java-sdk-logs 1.10.2, which is **not** compatible with other aws-java-sdk libraries 1.11.0 and above.  We do use a number of other aws-java-sdk libraries. We excluded the dependency like this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eluder.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-ext-cloudwatch-appender</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-logs</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-logs</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.5</version>
</dependency>
```

At that point we started getting another error.

```
 Exception in thread "org.myorg.task.MyTask working" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.services.logs.AWSLogsClient.createLogGroup(Lcom/amazonaws/services/logs/model/CreateLogGroupRequest;)V
         at org.eluder.logback.ext.cloudwatch.appender.AbstractCloudWatchAppender.createLogGroup(AbstractCloudWatchAppender.java:171)
         at org.eluder.logback.ext.cloudwatch.appender.AbstractCloudWatchAppender.doStart(AbstractCloudWatchAppender.java:107)
         at org.eluder.logback.ext.aws.core.AbstractAwsEncodingStringAppender.start(AbstractAwsEncodingStringAppender.java:123)
         at org.eluder.logback.ext.cloudwatch.appender.AbstractCloudWatchAppender.start(AbstractCloudWatchAppender.java:95)
         at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:90)
         at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:309)
         at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:193)
         at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:179)
         at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
         at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:155)
         at ch.qos.logback.core.sift.SiftingJoranConfiguratorBase.doConfigure(SiftingJoranConfiguratorBase.java:82)
         at ch.qos.logback.core.sift.AbstractAppenderFactoryUsingJoran.buildAppender(AbstractAppenderFactoryUsingJoran.java:51)
         at ch.qos.logback.core.sift.AppenderTracker.buildComponent(AppenderTracker.java:56)
         at ch.qos.logback.core.sift.AppenderTracker.buildComponent(AppenderTracker.java:32)
         at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AbstractComponentTracker.getOrCreate(AbstractComponentTracker.java:124)
         at ch.qos.logback.core.sift.SiftingAppenderBase.append(SiftingAppenderBase.java:104)
         at ch.qos.logback.core.AppenderBase.doAppend(AppenderBase.java:82)
         at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:48)
         at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:270)
         at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:257)
         at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:421)
         at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
         at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.info(Logger.java:579)
```

Merely excluding the dependencies did not work.  I had to fork and rebuild the logback-ext-cloudwatch-appender jar with a dependency on the current 1.11.5 aws-java-sdk libraries.  Trying to use the new AWS dependencies with the logback-ext-cloudwatch-appender jar which had been built against the old libraries caused a mismatch in the method signature (return type) of createLogGroup which caused a runtime error.  To get this to run, I only had to change the pom.xml files, not the source code, in my forked version.

Comment: I interpreted this answer as "go take a look at my dependencies." I updated my `aws-java-sdk` and `aws-java-sdk-core` to the latest versions as shown on MavenCentral and it fixed the error for me!

Comment: If you're not using the logback-ext-cloudwatch-appender like we are, which is not a part of AWS, then yes, I agree.  That's the high level description of how to get to the fix.

Comment: I had the same problem in my cloudwatch appender. I think I worked around it using reflection on the createLogGroup call: https://github.com/j256/cloudwatch-logback-appender/commit/9524f6c095139635c8128ab2ec75c5487da9bf82